# Bootstrap-wysihtml5: content uneditable

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I'm trying to implement bootstrap-wysihtml5 by jhollingworth.

On one of my pages it works perfectly, but on a different page the content is uneditable.
The code is almost identical (except for layout, ...), but if I do "Inspect Element" in Google chrome, I see 2 different outputs.

Working code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<textarea id="msgcompose_msg"></textarea>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#msgcompose_msg").wysihtml5();
});
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Output: http://i.imm.io/1gGDY.png

Not working code:

```
<p>
<textarea id="forum_topic_view_reply_reply"></textarea>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("forum_topic_view_reply_reply").wysihtml5();
});
</script>
</p>
```

Output: http://i.imm.io/1gGEy.png

Personally I don't know why the output is different

Comment: Have you got a js file in the file that doesn't work

Comment: please can you make a fiddle so that we can test

Answer (score 0):

Found the error it was in this line:

```
$("forum_topic_view_reply_reply").wysihtml5();
```

You need this instead:

```
$("#forum_topic_view_reply_reply").wysihtml5();
```

As there was no hashtag on the second instance of it the page was looking for a tag called `forum_topic_view_reply_reply` not an id

Comment: That must have been a typo on my part, because it doesn't make any difference, the wysihtml5() thing is still loading, only the textarea itself doesn't work..

Comment: @MrCoder try having the script outside of the p tag as it is bad practise to do so